# How do I listen for Google APIs Push notifications?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive api and I would like for my UWP app to be notified of changes made to a user’s files. Should there be some sort of event that I should be listening for which basically says, “ changes have occurred to your files”?

I just registered for a domain that will be used as part of the set up process since I guess it is a requirement. But googles documentation does nothing to explain the steps required to actually LISTEN out for changes.

Googles documentation: [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push)

Comment: You need to set up https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch

Answer (score 0):

The Drive API provides push notifications that let you watch for changes to resources. You can use this feature to improve the performance of your application. It allows you to eliminate the extra network and compute costs involved with polling resources to determine if they have changed. Whenever a watched resource changes, the Drive API notifies your application.

Push notifications will be sent to a central location on your server. when you register the domain of your receiving URL.   For example, if you plan to use https://exampe.com/notifications as your receiving URL, you need to register https://exampe.com.

Once you have set up the domain where you would like the push notifications sent to its simply a matter of setting up a watch on the file in question.

You need to set up [watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch) and then you will start recieving push notifications on changes of those files

> POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/watch

request body

```
{
  "kind": "api#channel",
  "id": string,
  "resourceId": string,
  "resourceUri": string,
  "token": string,
  "expiration": long,
  "type": string,
  "address": string,
  "payload": boolean,
  "params": {
    (key): string
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. And so exactly through what source will the push notification come through to the user's device? Will there be an event that is fired? This answer doesn't address my issue. I have no problem setting this up. But logically speaking, there has to be some way to LISTEN for the notification so that I can take action. Thanks again!

Comment: It does not come though to the users device.  It comes though to your server that you set up in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push  it will be up to you to send it to the users device.   Please check my edit i suspect you have missunderstood how push notifications work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I guess I would have to develop a huge infrastructure from scratch that listens for notifications from within my app. And then develop code on the server that sends that info out to each user's device? They make it seem so much simpler. There has to be some sort of api (maybe in Windows) that simplifies the process. Can the Windows Push Notification Service (WNS) somehow be used with this? Or is that something entirely different?

Comment: Sorry I can't answer that.  You may want to ask another question related to push notifications for windows.   I can only answer about Google drive which is what your question is asking